# kubectl (version v1.15.0) on windows is not able to display the tabular output using 'get' command with default content type

Tags: windows, powershell, kubernetes

kubectl version v1.15.0 was not able to list the pods (and other resources) in tabular form of content type using 'get' command.

```
kubectl get pods
Error from server (NotAcceptable): the server was unable to respond with a content type that the client supports (get pods)
```

I tried this using cygwin, cmd & powershell.

Comment: This works with kubectl version v1.9.6

Comment: Looks like the client indicated types not accepted by the server. From the source code:
`StatusReasonNotAcceptable means that the accept types indicated by the client were not acceptable to the server - for instance, attempting to receive protobuf for a resource that supports only json and yaml.`
That doesn't say much but for a start, are you sure you're using the correct [kubectl binary](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.15.md#client-binaries)?